# restrict Google API Key by HTTP referrer (client side) OR IP address (server side)

Tags: google-api, google-authentication, google-apis-explorer, google-developers-console

Is it possible to restrict Google API Key by HTTP referrer (client side) OR IP address (server side)?

The image below shows where I set this in the API console.  The problem is that I have to choose the restriction by type (i.e. I can not restrict by HTTP Referrer and/or IP address).

[image: Screenshot from Google API]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the only options that you have.  You can choose one or the other not both.

Suggestion There is a feedback option in the upper right hand corner of the google developer console. What you suggest is a good idea i suggest you submit it as a feature request that it be possible to select more then one type.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create two API keys, one for each purpose?

Comment: Many CMS plugins and third-party packages accept only one API key to do back-end and front-end work. In those cases, you cannot have two API keys. Granted those tools could be changed to accept two keys, but I am afraid that applying IP (back-end) and referrer (front-end) restriction on the key side is a much more simple and clean solution, isn't?